# How to share a derived member variable with the base class

Tags: c#

I'm using Xamarin to make an Android and iOS app. I have my code split into 3 projects: Android, iOS and common. The code is basically designed such that common code is abstract and handles the the OS agnostic side of things and the Android/iOS code inherits from the common and handles the OS specific things. However, I'm tripping over how to handle custom member variables following this paradigm, as I need to hold onto a OS specific instance so that the class can do OS things, but I also need to reference the OS specific instance in the common code to commonly handle things.

Example: A common class is comprised of a question and a chart (think public survey where you can see how other people responded). The common version of these things are responsible for retrieving their data from the appropriate places (database, server). The OS specific version of these things are responsible for displaying the UI. I would like to pass into this class the Android version of the question and chart. Then I can call the class' "retrieveData" (common) function and the class' "displayUi" (OS specific function). I would really like to reference the same member variables during this process.

If I program it 'normally', the common class would contain the common class of question and chart and the inherited Android class would access this variables. But this doesn't work because when the Android class access them, it gets the variables as common and doesn't have the OS specific functionality. If I put the variables in the Android class, then the base class doesn't know about them and I can't do common things with them.

Up to this point, I've gotten around this by using Generics. But I've recently ran into a problem with that solution ([Inheriting generic can't up cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743271/inheriting-generic-cant-up-cast)). Another solution I've thought of is using the 'new' operator on a property in the Android class to mask the inherited member variable and use the get function to automatically down cast the variable into the Android version and the set function to store the variable on the base (base.variable = value). I'm not too keen on this idea as I have to double declare the variables and I have a slight problem with collections of variables (I can either use Array.Convert (or some similar method) if I need to pass in the array/list/dictionary/etc, or I can cast as I iterate though it to do whatever it is I have to do. Not great, but doable.

I'm curious if there's other ways to to handle this situation .

#### Edit

Here's some simplified code:

```
public interface IAnsweredCommon { ... }
```

```
public interface IAnsweredAndroid : IAnsweredCommon { ... }
```

```
public abstract class ConstructorCommon<AnsweredType> where AnsweredType : IAnsweredCommon
{
  protected AnsweredType Answered;

  ...
}
```

```
public class ConstructorAndroid : ConstructorCommon<IAnsweredAndroid> { ... }
```

As you can see, this version is using the generic pattern. ConstructorCommon has a variable of type AnsweredType which is treated as IAnsweredCommon within the class allowing it to do non-OS specific things with it. ConstructorAndroid inherits from ConstructorCommon using IAnsweredAndroid. This allows me to instantiate ConstructorAndroid without having to specify a type and allows it to treat the inherited AnsweredType as a IAnsweredAndroid to do OS specific things.

As mentioned in the previous question; this generic way won't work for an unrelated reason. So, to make code work in that question, I need away to replicate what the generic is doing. The only other way I can think of, is to change the Answered variable type from AnsweredType to IAnsweredCommon and to implement a new property in ConstructorAndroid that hides the Answered variable (via the 'new' keyword) and implement the get to return a casted base variable and set to set the base variable:

```
public abstract class ConstructorCommon
{
  protected IAnsweredCommon Answered;

  ...
}
```

```
public class ConstructorAndroid : ConstructorCommon
{

  protected new IAnsweredAndroid Answered
  {
    get => (IAnsweredAndroid)base.Answered;
    set => base.Answered = value;
  }

  ...
}
```

I'm not super crazy about this idea for the reasons I stated above, so I'm curious if there's another way.

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: Simplified version of the code please

Comment: My first thoughts are that you either need to declare some of these methods as `virtual` or you need interfaces/abstract base classes for some of these classes.  As others have commented, seeing the code would probably tell us which.

Comment: Based on this and your last question, inheritance may not be the right answer. Maybe you need something more like the Strategy pattern. Plug in an implementation for each OS-specific presentation.

Comment: the same class can retrieve data from db and display the UI? big smell IMHO. I would split funcionalities in different classes, here it seems you are driving in the opposite direction of [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)